# ASP.Net when post back get The specified URL cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, postback

When clicking the save button on a asp.net web form page, I get the following immediately:

The specified URL cannot be found

This does not happen when I try this using a browser on the web server.

Has anyone run across this problem before? Is this some kind of security issue?

---

More information. I tried a test page that included all of the form fields and a button that didn't do anything but write to a log4net log. Same problem on the button click. This is just weird.

Comment: Can you include a code sample?

Comment: I considered including code but it is HUGE, lots of data entry fields.

Answer (score 8):

Found the solution to this!!! Turns out the firewall was blocking request that had more then 40 parameters in the query string.

Comment: Specifically in my case it was a Barracuda Web Application Firewall (WAF) that was not allowing POSTs to specific application URLs because the max number of 40 parameters was exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more information?
This could be caused by a lot of things:

- Is IIS configured properly for the site? Authentication, host header settings?
- Did you try http://localhost/.. on the webserver or did you use the webserver's host name?
- Are you redirecting the user? What are you doing in the button event?
- Are you using URL routing? Or a handler that might be causing problems?
- What version of the .NET framework are you running? 1.1 / 2.0 / higher?
- Does the page include javascript that could cause unexpected results?
- Checked for crazy stuff in your web.config?

Sometimes it's a good idea to take a step back and create a new ASPX page and test if that one works. Start from a predictable scenario and move towards your current scenario in baby steps.

Comment: IIS is configured correctly as far as I can tell, I used the host name while testing on the server, no redirect, button click collects the data and saves it, no url routing, code targets 3.5 framework, jquery javascript is included in script tags, no crazy stuff in web config that I can see. I like your idea of trying a simple page and baby stepping. Thanks!

Comment: FYI - test page worked fine. put some logging in my real page in the page load and it was never hit. appears that the form is not posting correctly for some reason.

Comment: Did you try to transfer some of the code to your test page? You might also want to check the form tag in the HTML source of your page (after rendering)