# "The specified URL cannot be found" on postback - asp.net windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, windows-authentication

I have a .net web application that uses Windows Authentication. It's an intranet, hosted on AWS, and has WAF.

Half that times, when there's a postback action, the browser immediately returns a 404 error in console with the message "The specified URL cannot be found." on the page. This seems to only happen in Chrome and Edge, NOT IE.

Both server settings and web.config have Windows Authentication enabled.

The server log shows some 401.2 errors but from my reading, it seems to be a normal process for Windows Authentication, some kind of authentication challenge. These 401.2 error lines also register for IE browser which reaffirms this theory.

The error happens before the web application is able to catch any errors. Even with errorMode set to Detailed, the browser only displays that "specified URL cannot be found" message.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Subset of my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259676/asp-net-when-post-back-get-the-specified-url-cannot-be-found) with similar problem. The main problem was the number of parameters exceeded 40, causing WAF to block the request. Based on the headers info, my request only sends 10 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out WAF was blocking request due to high header counts. The issue is resolved by increasing the header counts.

Comment: How can the header counts be increased? Editing that instruction to your answer would make it more useful for future readers.